# get only one data from right join mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have table 2 table in my database

**1. chats**

| id | phone_number | messages | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 898000211900 | Hallo bos, mana utangmu? | 2021-10-25 11:36:26 |
| 1 | 898000211900 | Hai | 2021-10-25 09:36:26 |
| 1 | 798000211901 | P | 2021-10-25 09:36:26 |

**2. contacts**

| id | phone_number | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 898000211900 | Illam |

i want to make query to this table that show only one messages (latest), like this :

| phone_number | name | messages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 898000211900 | Illam | Hallo bos, mana utangmu? |
| 798000211901 | NULL | P |

i have tried with RIGHT JOIN but the results its wrong

```
select 
contacts.name, 
contacts.phone_number,
chats.messages
from contacts
right join chats
on contacts.phone_number = chats.phone_number
order by chats.created_at desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for NULL values in the 2nd table

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

SELECT contacts.name, contacts.phone_number, chats.messages
FROM contacts RIGHT JOIN chats
ON contacts.phone_number = chats.phone_number
GROUP BY contacts.phone_number
HAVING chats.name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY chats.created_at DESC
```

Comment: its show all of message, i want to show last message (only one) from each contact

Comment: Updated my answer, check now

Comment: its show error Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: Updated my answer, run that query to change the sql_mode